# YouTube support removed from JWPlayer version 8 (JW8)

Tags: youtube, jwplayer

The release notes for JWPlayer v8, indicate that support for embedding YouTube videos has been dropped:

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2870361-introducing-jw8

Here's a conversation about it on Github that they have locked:

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/2233

I enjoyed using JWPlayer because I could use the same api and player interface for embedding YouTube videos and non-YouTube videos.

Is anyone developing a JWPlayer provider for YouTube?  Is there an alternative to JWPlayer that supports YouTube and non-YouTube videos?

Comment: I'm tempted to develop YouTube plugin for JW Player 8 - I just need to assess the demand versus potential headache! Meanwhile, there are a number of alternative YouTube wrapping players which might suit your needs - Mediaelementjs, Plyr, Clappr, - whether they meet your requirements will likely depend on the specific functionality you are using the API for.

Comment: JWPlayer was the best third party player for playing YT videos. However, in your case, I advise you to use the native YouTube HTML5 Video Player
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Github issue here where the Youtube provider code used in the repo before it was removed can be found: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/2894